# Cant install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 on HP 650 - Cant recognize Windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, hp, raid

I have a notebook HP 650 and I removed Windows 8 to install Windows 7. I have disabled Secureboot and installed Win7 successfully.

When I boot Ubuntu live cd, the installation manager is unable to detect Windows partition and it is showing all the HDD as "unallocated" so I have no way to resize partition and install Ubuntu without destroying Windows partition.

Same thing is happening with Gparted that prompts me that cant detect if HDD is GPT or not.

Searching internet I found that HP notebooks have a RAID controller that prevents Windows to be properly detected but using the command  *sudo dmraid -rE*  I get the "No RAID detected"

I have been setting dual boot frequently for friends etc but this is the first time I can't find a solution.

The most strange is that this notebook is Ubuntu certified http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201209-11786/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before, if you had windows 8 installed previously maybe is a GPT data left behind by it, try booting ubuntu in "Try Ubuntu without installing it" mode then

1. Open the terminal and
2. type `sudo gdisk /dev/sdx` (change `/dev/sdx` for the proper access to you disk, use gparted to know which `/dev/` is in case you have doubts)
3. then press `X` to enter in expert mode in this mode.
4. then type `z` to destroy the GPT data,
5. type `Y` to confirm the action.

NOW BE EXTRA CAREFUL because then will ask you about blanking MBR and you MUST respond NO (`n`) if you answer yes it will destroy the current windows partitions, this worked for me.