# Cant install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS alongside Win 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I m trying to install Ubuntu on my hp laptop which he has Win 7. I followed the steps for installing but got some problems now, like I don't have the option to "install-alongside-windows ". Also I have unallocated space for the Ubuntu partition but nothing shows when i go to "Choose Something else".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy70U.jpg

Comment: Make the unallocated space FAT32 and go back and try to install. The filesystem will change when the OS is being installed.

Comment: Was you laptop pre-installed with win 8 ?

Comment: Is your drive encrypted? Drive encryptions will create problems with parallel installation.

Comment: @CheddieMerai i will try that and will tell if it helps

Comment: No it wasnt win8 preinstaled, and the drive wasnt encrypted.

Comment: I have made the unallocated space fat32 and still the same problem :(

Comment: I have searched all day for solution for my problem and still cant get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

[Cant install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 on HP 650 - Cant recognize Windows partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518669/cant-install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-7-on-hp-650-cant-recognize-windows-parti?rq=1)

The answer in this question helped, and now i have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows successfully and i have dual boot.